# HTML tag closing with php code

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
  <a class='example-image-link' href='images/<?php echo addslashes($elevations);?>' data-lightbox='example-set' title='Click on the right side of the image to move forward.'><?php echo addslashes($elevations);?></a>
```

In the code above the `<a>` tag closes where the php tag `?>` closes. The `<a>` closing `"/>`" tag does not close after the "title" but closes here :`<?php echo addslashes($elevations);?>` i.e. after the ? .

What is the possible cause and how should I rectify this?

Comment: not cleared what u want to say but is it...href='<?php echo "images/".addslashes($elevations);?>'

Comment: Post the output of : `var_dump(addslashes($elevations))`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, something else is breaking it. What results are you expecting? I will bet my bottom dollar that it's your `$elevations` variable which isn't set or formatted correctly. Maybe even your Lightbox JS.

Comment: @Fred:
I tried <?php

echo "<a class='example-image-link' href='images/".addslashes($elevations)."' data-lightbox='example-set' title='Click on the right side of the image to move forward.'>".addslashes($elevations)."</a>";

?> suggsted here by one person but Lightbox effect is not shown

Comment: @user2822187 What is the value of `$elevations` variable? That's what I need to know and see.

Comment: I am getting the image from the database. that is the variable for getiing the image.. But in the above code it is not even displaying the image..

Comment: @user2822187 Then the problem is in your DB field and not your posted code. It may be adding quotes to it. Try and use `stripslashes` instead of `addslashes` or even `htmlentities`

Comment: @user2822187 So, have you tried my suggestion of using `stripslashes` or `htmlentities` instead of `addslashes` ?

Comment: Fred:
Thanks fro the reply. Yes I have tried but it is not working . I guess I will have to change my database. I will keep in contact with you here and let you know when I get the results and if I have any more problem.

Comment: @Fred:
It works with only one entry of the database. And yes I did use stripslashes as you suggsted. I dont understand why it does not work with other db entries.. i am checking that out.

Comment: @Fred: Hi Fred.. I had to modify my db..Now I am getting the images but the lightbox effect is not implemented propelry.. Bu thanks a lot for the help.. Most of my problem got solved..

Comment: @user2822187 You're welcome. Least now you're starting to get results.

Comment: @Fred:
Yup.. I had to modify things tht were done by previous developers

Answer (score 0):

if you get the error from above then simply do the following

```
<?php

echo "<a class='example-image-link' href='images/".addslashes($elevations)."' data-lightbox='example-set' title='Click on the right side of the image to move forward.'>".addslashes($elevations)."</a>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what you are saying, but i thing may be issue in your href tag, try below

```
href= "<?php echo "images/".addslashes($elevations);?>"
```

Comment: What is happening is the a tag angular bracket ">" should close after title='Click on the right side of the image to move forward.'>.. i.e. after the words "forward.' but it closes at ($elevations);?>' of the php code.. I tried your solution but it is not helping

Comment: try this ==>  <a class='example-image-link' href= "<?php echo "images/".addslashes($elevations);?>" data-lightbox='example-set' title='Click on the right side of the image to move forward.'><?php echo addslashes($elevations);?></a>

Comment: The problem is with the database wich was designed by former developer. the data in it has many problems wich m trying to sort out